# How do I wait for "whenGET" to finish using AngularJS / Karma unit testing framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

**How do I wait for `whenGET()` or `expectGET()` to finish** using AngularJS's unit test framework Karma / Jasmine?

## Unit Test for adminController:

```
'use strict';
//SETUP
describe('spec/controllers/admin.js - adminController', function () {
        var $controller;
        var $httpBackend;
        var scope;
        var testData_admin = {
          query: {
            input: ['ADMIN']

          }

    beforeEach(module('queueManagerApp','queueManagerApp-testTemplates'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$httpBackend_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        scope = {};
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $controller('adminController',{ $scope: scope });
    }));

    // makes sure all expected requests are made by the time the test ends
    afterEach(function() {
      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

//TESTS
    describe('http test ( Get user rights details -1 )', function () {
         it('admin user should have admin rights enabled (ADMIN)', function() {
             $httpBackend.whenGET('user/rights').respond(testData_admin);
             $controller('adminController',{ $scope: scope });
             var isAdmin = scope.isEnabled(testData_admin.query.input);
             $httpBackend.flush();
             expect(isAdmin).toEqual(true); //FAILING
         });
    });

});
```

## adminController:

```
'use strict';

function adminController($scope, $http, $location) {

//RUN THIS SECTION FIRST
    $scope.enabledRights = [];
    $http.get('user/rights').success(function(data) {
            $scope.enabledRights = data;
    }).error(function() {
            $scope.enabledRights = [];
    });

//RUN THIS SECTION SECOND
    var isAdmin = false;
    $scope.isEnabled = function(allowedRights) {                    
        if($scope.enabledRights.length > 0){
            if($scope.enabledRights.indexOf(allowedRights) > -1){
                isAdmin = true;             
            }else{
                isAdmin = false;            
            }
         }
      return isAdmin;
    }; 
}

angular
  .module('queueManagerApp')
  .controller('adminController',
        ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$filter', '$window', adminController]);
```

The problem that I'm running into is **this line:**

`$httpBackend.whenGET('user/rights').respond(testData_admin);`

**is running *AFTER* this line:**

`var isAdmin = scope.isEnabled(testData_admin.query.input);`

### So, **how do I force `whenGET` to run BEFORE the scope function `isEnabled`?** OR How do I wait until `whenGET` is done so I can then execute `isEnabled`?

Here's what I've tried:

---

## Try #1: Add `then` to `whenGET`

Didn't work. Said then is not a function

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('user/rights').respond(testData_admin).then(function(){
        $controller('adminController',{ $scope: scope });
        var isAdmin = scope.isEnabled(testData_admin.query.input);
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(isAdmin).toEqual(true);
});
```

---

## Try #2: Use `expectGET` instead of `whenGET`

When I run this I get `Unexpected GET Request 'user/rights'`

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('user/rights').respond(testData_admin);
$controller('adminController',{ $scope: scope });
var isAdmin = scope.isEnabled(testData_admin.query.input);
$httpBackend.flush();
expect(isAdmin).toEqual(true); //FAILING
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this?

[AngularJS's docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) say that whenGET and expectGET don't have callback functions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Will placing $httpBackend.whenGET('user/rights').respond(testData_admin); in the beforeEach block help?

Comment: @JaseemAbbas same error :/ kinda weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
describe('http test ( Get user rights details -1 )', function () {
     beforeEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.whenGET('user/rights').respond(testData_admin);
        $controller('adminController',{ $scope: scope });
     });
     it('admin user should have admin rights enabled (ADMIN)', function() {
         var isAdmin = scope.isEnabled(testData_admin.query.input);
         expect(isAdmin).toEqual(true); //FAILING
         $httpBackend.flush();
     });
});
```

Comment: "whenGET" is still running after "isEnabled" :/